# Testing of IO return value

Tags: unit-testing, haskell, testing, io

I have a statement that I need to check the return value of:

```
> let a = tRunUmeQuery (selectByCount "Word" "Acoustic" "=" ((toInteger 1):[]) Strict)  testdb
> :t a 
a :: IO [[SqlValue]]
```

So, I would like to make sure that `a` is a list with a length of exactly 6 (`IO 6` then).

```
> fmap length a
6
```

What would a testCase that checks this look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, the solution was not that complicated (I just managed to make it complicated in my head).

```
ucg :: TestTree
ucg = testGroup "selectByCount" 
    [ testCase "2 Words dominated by exactly 1 Acoustic" $ do 
        r <- fmap length  $ tRunUmeQuery (selectByCount "Word" "Acoustic" "=" ((toInteger 1):[]) Strict) testdb  
        assertEqual "selectByCount: 1 Acoustic in Word" 6 r
    ]
```

This TestGroup works just fine.